# how can i retrieve the boolean values from database and display in a listview in phonegap?

Tags: jquery, cordova

i have created a local database using phonegap in that i was trying to retrieve 
boolean value from database and display in a list view..for that i want to design a 
check box and for that check box want to keep star image,when i click on star it has to update the value in database and retrieve list in a listview..please have a look at this screenshot for better idea..
how can i do this for my code..

```
$('#Allwordslist').append('<li><a href="#"><h3 class="ui-li-heading">'+row['Word']+'</h3><p class="ui-li-desc">'+row['Type_Of_Word']+'</p></a></li>');
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

use jquery mobile listviews http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html

Comment: thanks for the reply,i came to know how to display in a listview..i want to know,how can i update boolean values into database..here am using sqlite db in phonegap..